# How do I add cv2 as a requirement in a python package?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, python-packaging

I'm trying to make my own package which uses OpenCV Python module `cv2`. However when using PyCharm, it warns that the

> Package requirement is not satisfied.

I suspect this is because I used the recommended method of copy/pasting `cv2.pyd` into my python dir. Note that `pip install cv2`  doesn't work.

What's the right method to ensure that requirements are met when this package is brought in?

EDIT:

My setup.py file is as follows

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='image_processing',
      version='0.1',
      install_requires=['numpy', 'scipy', 'cv2'],
      description='Collection of useful image processing functions',
      url='',
      author='Bill',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['image_processing'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

This is where the error shows up when trying to package my code. Normally I have no issues importing numpy or cv2. I installed Numpy using pip, and cv2 via the method mentioned above. Everything works if I just run scripts using cv2, but it's this packaging that's tricking me up.

Comment: Are you able to `import numpy`? Their website states that `numpy` is required. Another option might be to try this unofficial port: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

Comment: Yeah, normally I have no issues using `numpy` or `cv2`. But trying to create a package that uses `cv2` is causing an issue (see edit in post). I considered using the unofficial port, but I want to be sure that what I add in the future will be in line with OpenCV standards (and that I'll have clear docs for new functions).

Comment: Oh, so that's the problem. `cv2` is not a package that can be installed. If you copy/pasted the `cv2.pyd` file to your project, I don't think you need to put it under `install_requires`, just make sure that file is delivered with your package or that the users can add that file themselves.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case.

Answer (score 13):

You need to add `opencv-python` to requirements.

The package is here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

Then, your `requirements.txt` file is OK, but sometimes PyCharm keeps whining. If this is the case, then next to the "Install requirement" label there is "Ignore requirement". The latter is your way to go.

(current - 2018.2 PyCharm version does not complain about `cv2` when `opencv-python` is specified in requirements)

Comment: What if it has to be the official opencv? What should be put there? Perhaps in this case it's left out and just specified as a sort of requirement in the README?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai have you found a solution? I believe python has no way of specifying such requirements :(

Comment: unfortunately Pycharm (2018.2) still complains about cv2 if opencv-python-headless is specified in the requirements

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the version of the opencv python package.
"pip install opencv-python==2.4.9"

Find the proper version from [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/).

If you want to install latest opencv python package, use
"pip install opencv-python"